# Import-CSV Taking Forever Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-2.0, import-csv

I am trying to `import-csv` of a file that is 3GB and store it in a variable and then run a script based on all that data. I need all the information in the file. The import command is taking hours though to import the data. Is there a faster way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: It is what there is built in to PowerShell, if you want something faster either code your own `Import-Csv` using `System.IO` and splitting techniques or use a different language

Answer (score 1):

Look into `System.IO.StreamReader` and `System.IO.File`. When I had to process a large - tens or hundreds of thousands of lines - CSV file, that was the only way I could do it with any efficiency.

Here's an example.

```
$FileReader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($FileName)
While ($FileLine = $FileReader.ReadLine())
{
    # Do Things with $FileLine
}
$FileReader.Close()
```

Comment: I will look into this! Thank you. Is it possible to use a foreach loop when using System.IO.File to read the csv? Currently I am importing the csv as a variable and then using a foreach loop to loop through all the data

Comment: @Schmit yes... you can just surround it in a `foreach ($file in $listoffiles){ ///script here///}`.

Comment: Thanks! One more question, would it be better to use OpenText and then read each line like you have in the example above or to use ReadAllText?

Comment: I believe ReadLine prevents the entire file from being loaded into memory where `ReadAllText` "Opens a text file, reads all the text in the file into a string, and then closes the file."